# Is there a word or phrase for this specific kind of abuse of ambiguity?

Tags: single-word-requests

In *Peter Pan 2: Return to Never Land*, Captain Hook promises not to harm a single hair on Peter's head. Then, he plucks a single hair off of Peter's head and claims that is the one he chooses not to harm. The cleverness stems from the fact that we assume he meant **any** hairs on his head, but grammatically it could also refer to just a **single** hair. I know the phrase is an idiom, but I'm more interested in if there's a word for the logical substitution that can be made in the phrase.

Comment: In this *specific* case, is it appropriate to say that (semantically speaking) Captain Hook was ***splitting hairs**?* Which isn't that far removed from ***nit-picking*** (searching for metaphorical fleas eggs in someone's hair!).

Comment: From the earlier question cited as a duplicate; 'In English, sentences containing both a negative and a quantifier, or a negative and a modal, or a modal and a quantifier, are ambiguous, unless some care is taken in phrasing them.... In English, sentences containing both a negative and a quantifier, or a negative and a modal, or a modal and a quantifier, are ambiguous, unless some care is taken in phrasing them. ....' [John Lawler] So here, '**negation-quantifier ambiguity**'.

Comment: Whatever - I don't see anything in the linked duplicate that looks like an answer to the *specific* question being asked here (is there a *name* for it?). So I offer [***literalism***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/literalism) - ***The interpretation of words in their literal sense***.

Comment: @FF They're both literal readings.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: True, but only ***one*** of those "literal" meanings would normally be intended (and understood). And what matters in OP's context is that the ***other*** interpretation is the one that's actually intended by the speaker. I doubt there's a word for *deliberately choosing phrasing which is **literally** true, but intended to be misunderstood*, but I stand to be corrected. In which context the term "plausible deniability" seems at least "relevant".

Comment: @FF 'Perverse construal' is used but obviously refers to all instances of demanding a non-pragmatic reading where there is technical ambiguity: 'He agreed to a lump-sum payment in 1998 without realizing that the arbitrator's perverse construal of "a football injury" ...'. [[cited by Zimmer; LanguageLog](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005048.html)]